# Split java.util.stream.Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a text file that contains URLs and emails. I need to extract all of them from the file. Each URL and email can be found more then once, but result shouldn't contain duplicates.
I can extract all URLs using the following code:

```
Files.lines(filePath).
    .map(urlPattern::matcher)
    .filter(Matcher::find)
    .map(Matcher::group)
    .distinct();
```

I can extract all emails using the following code:

```
Files.lines(filePath).
    .map(emailPattern::matcher)
    .filter(Matcher::find)
    .map(Matcher::group)
    .distinct();
```

Can I extract all URLs and emails reading the stream returned by `Files.lines(filePath)` only one time?
Something like splitting stream of lines to stream of URLs and stream of emails.

Comment: `Stream<String> fileStream = Files.lines(Paths.get("test"));
  fileStream.//email match
  fileStream.//url match` The only solution that comes into my mind, when your problem is that you don't want to create 2 streams

Comment: I guess, storing the lines into `List` and traversing it twice is not qualified as a solution, correct?

Comment: Loki, you cannot traverse the same stream twice.

Comment: Didn't know that. But so we all learn something ;)

Comment: @TagirValeev Storing in a `List` and traversing twice is definitely what I would do in this scenario, it seems like the best solution I can think of.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `partitioningBy` collector, though it's still not very elegant solution.

```
Map<Boolean, List<String>> map = Files.lines(filePath)
        .filter(str -> urlPattern.matcher(str).matches() ||
                       emailPattern.matcher(str).matches())
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(str -> urlPattern.matcher(str).matches()));
List<String> urls = map.get(true);
List<String> emails = map.get(false);
```

If you don't want to apply regexp twice, you can make it using the intermediate pair object (for example, `SimpleEntry`):

```
public static String classify(String str) {
    return urlPattern.matcher(str).matches() ? "url" : 
        emailPattern.matcher(str).matches() ? "email" : null;
}

Map<String, Set<String>> map = Files.lines(filePath)
        .map(str -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(classify(str), str))
        .filter(e -> e.getKey() != null)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(),
            Collectors.mapping(e -> e.getValue(), Collectors.toSet())));
```

Using my free [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library the last step would be shorter:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map = StreamEx.of(Files.lines(filePath))
        .mapToEntry(str -> classify(str), Function.identity())
        .nonNullKeys()
        .grouping(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: I edited my answer, added calling `matcher.group(1)` to extract URL or email from string. Would ge great, if you add this to your code, that it become correct.

Comment: The question used `.distinct()` after filtering which suggests that collecting to `Set`s rather than `List`s  is more appropriate. Generally, the `classify` method is a good idea, making it easier to use existing `Collector`s rather than implementing a custom `Collector` (like i did)

Comment: @york.beta: there is no point in using `group(1)` as long as you use `matches` as that implies that the entire `String` matches. It would be different if you used `find` but then it would be an entirely different question as it implies the possibility of have both pattern finding a match within the same line…

Comment: @Holger I use regexp something like this: `/^.*(<url regexp>).*$/` and imply that string can contain only one URL or email. So `group(1)` is necessary to extract URL or email.

Comment: @york.beta: that really sounds like you should use `find` instead and as said, it implies that you should think about what to do if both pattern find a match within the same line or even more than one match… `^.*regexp.*$` clearly is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @york.beta: isn't it possible that both e-mail and url appear in the same line? And what if there are several urls/emails there?

Comment: This is just example, so you can imply that each string contains only one URL or email. In real life each string maps to set of URLs and emails, and demainds calling `Stream.flatMap`.

Comment: @york.beta: if this is “just an example” why do you insist of the solution calling `group(1)` even if the underlying pattern isn’t known? Regardless of what the real life application does, if it combines `matches` with `group(n)`, it’s very likely to be wrong. Even if it’s guaranteed that there is at most one match, using the actual pattern without `.*` etc and `find()` and `group()` (without number) is the right tool.

Comment: @Holger You are right. I use Java not very often, so called `matches()` instead of `find()`. Is right chain of calls looks like: `m = urlPattern.matcher(line); String url = m.find() ? m.group() : null`?

Comment: @york.beta: if you want to deal with `null` then, it’s the right chain.

Answer (score 4):

You can perform the matching within a `Collector`:

```
Map<String,Set<String>> map=Files.lines(filePath)
    .collect(HashMap::new,
        (hm,line)-> {
            Matcher m=emailPattern.matcher(line);
            if(m.matches())
              hm.computeIfAbsent("mail", x->new HashSet<>()).add(line);
            else if(m.usePattern(urlPattern).matches())
              hm.computeIfAbsent("url", x->new HashSet<>()).add(line);
        },
        (m1,m2)-> m2.forEach((k,v)->m1.merge(k, v,
                                     (s1,s2)->{s1.addAll(s2); return s1;}))
    );
Set<String> mail=map.get("mail"), url=map.get("url");
```

Note that this can easily be adapted to find multiple matches within a line:

```
Map<String,Set<String>> map=Files.lines(filePath)
    .collect(HashMap::new,
        (hm,line)-> {
            Matcher m=emailPattern.matcher(line);
            while(m.find())
              hm.computeIfAbsent("mail", x->new HashSet<>()).add(m.group());
            m.usePattern(urlPattern).reset();
            while(m.find())
              hm.computeIfAbsent("url", x->new HashSet<>()).add(m.group());
        },
        (m1,m2)-> m2.forEach((k,v)->m1.merge(k, v,
                                     (s1,s2)->{s1.addAll(s2); return s1;}))
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't reuse a Stream, the only option would be to "do it manually" I think.

```
File.lines(filePath).forEach(s -> /** match and sort into two lists */ );
```

If there's another solution for this though I'd be happy to learn about it!

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, I'm curious is there another solution, so answered this question.

Answer (score 0):

The overall question should be: Why would you want to stream only once?

Extracting the URLs and extracting the emails are different operations and thus should be handled in their own streaming operations. Even if the underlying stream source contains hundreds of thousands of records, the time for iteration can be neglected when compared to the mapping and filtering operations.

The only thing you should consider as a possible performance issue is the IO operation. The cleanest solution therefore is to read the file only once and then stream on a resulting collection twice:

```
List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(filePath);
allLines.stream() ... // here do the URLs
allLines.stream() ... // here do the emails
```

Of course this requires some memory.

Comment: Sometimes it might be reasonable to do this in one pass. For example, input file contains millions of lines of which only a tiny bit satisfies the regexps.

Comment: Extracting URLs and emails is just an example, I'd like to extract another data from a few huge files. So reading them to memory or reading them a few times are not solutions.